# Deletions of clarifying comments from the OP

Tags: discussion, comments

A number of clarifying comments from the OP were unceremoniously deleted from "[Am I being asked to lie in my job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/97725/am-i-being-asked-to-lie-in-my-job)" (they were attached to the top answer, I believe).

While I understand the SE-wide policy of cleaning up excessive numbers of comments, my recollection is that several of the comments that were deleted were attempts from the OP to clarify the situation and provide additional details. Deleting these means that information is lost and answers are less informed and useful.

Why were these comments not preserved, merged into the question, or, at a minimum, archived to chat before they were deleted?

Answer (score 3):

The OP has only ever posted two comments on this site.  One of them was on that answer and is deleted.  (It's obsolete.)

The rest of the deleted comments on that answer are speculation and discussion about the company's motives 
among *other* users.  Some of those comments were heated, even rude.  I'm not the mod who handled the flags, but I agree with the outcome.  If the discussion had been polite and constructive it probably would have gone to chat instead.

Comment: Thanks. My recollection is that the OP provided more information that was of relevance, but I'm obviously going off of memory since I can't see what was said anymore, and I'll take your word that it wasn't important. It was still surprising to see such a substantial discussion completely deleted without any indication whatsoever.

Comment: @ZachLipton Comments aren't intended for discussion and *are* intended to be ephemeral. If a discussion did start and there is something of value in it we often move it to chat, though we can only do that once. But mindless speculation and guessing games at the motivations of the people involved in the question are often pointless and unceremoniously deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I have been a regular visitor to this site for about 2 years now. My observation is the moderators always *move* the comments to a chat room, and do not delete them unless they are rude or in violation of the "Be Nice" policy. They are also very lenient in interpreting "nice" in the latter case, as users can typically get away with snarky remarks that are not outright abusive.

It is <s>impossible</s> highly unlikely that a moderator would delete clarifying comments from the OP without merging them into the question description.

Comment: I would add in an "intentionally" there. :) We are only human and it sometimes happens that a comment from the OP that wasn't (yet) included in the main question is caught in a mass-deletion. But that's fairly rare and it's certainly not what happened here.